# Unable to set DRJIT LIB LLVM Path when trying to use Mitsuba Renderer in python

Tags: python, graphics, render, jit

I had a question on running Mitsuba.
So im going through some tutorials and if I need to use the mi.set_variant(‘llvm_ad_rgb’) llvm variant of Mitsuba, I am unable to use the llvm successfully.

I have installed llvm, but I get this error:

“AttributeError: jit_init_thread_state(): the LLVM backend is inactive because the LLVM shared library (“libLLVM.dylib”) could not be found! Set the DRJIT_LIBLLVM_PATH environment variable to specify its path.”

I have found this file “libLLVM.dylib” in the following location: ~/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libLLVM.dylib

and so i did a export DRJIT_LIBLLVM_PATH=“~/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libLLVM.dylib”
if i do echo $DRJIT_LIBLLVM_PATH I successfully get
~/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libLLVM.dylib

However, I am still getting the same error message.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks!